# PHP: __callStatic alternative for 5.2.x

Tags: php, static, call, magic-methods

So I have hosting that refuses to update to PHP 5.3 (which is annoying but fine at the same time; I'm flexible), but the only thing that is really ticking me off is not having __callStatic available.

I have modules loaded that I'm wanting to consolidate down to a single class (i.e. have a class that loads modules, and then accesses those modules' functions through calls to the main class' __callStatic method), but when I uploaded from a local testing server to my server, obviously the __callStatic method didn't work.

Is there an alternative that is *still* static? I like the clean code look for the double colon (i.e. `registry::some_func()`) instead of `$registry->some_func()`.

Another down-side to this is that I'm now forced to use the `global` keyword within functions (which by my own preference is very, *very* messy).

The code was also extremely fast using static methods instead of non-static methods, and in-turn much more clean.

**Also:** I've thought about writing the __callStatic method as usual with the 5.2 and then calling the methods explicitly, for example `registry::__callStatic("some_func"), array("val", "val2", "val3")` and keeping things simpler that way, even being easier to migrate when they do upgrade to 5.3. Thoughts on this method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only reason for wanting to do this is speed and subjective appeal of the double-colon, I would say grow to appreciate the tao of the dash-and-bracket, take the plunge and use object instances. The "clean code look" you speak of is like Hammer pants... cool one year, not so cool a few years later when you are older and wiser. `__callStatic()` (IMVHO) is an unnecessary minor convenience at best and a workaround for poor class design at worst. :)

Comment: Very Wisely spoken :] I agree with the fact that it's pretty much my own specification at this point. I can always use a little magic linux commands piped together to replace the entirety of the code with the static calls if need be (just removing the `$` and replacing the `->` with `::`. Thanks!